# Motorola s305 Headphones on Ubuntu 12.04. They work perfectly on Ubuntu 10.04. Why? How to fix?

Tags: 12.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have a set of motorola s305 bluetooth head phones.  These head phones work PERFECTLY on ubuntu 10.04 64bit (high and low quality, microphone as well).  I tried Ubuntu 11.04 and the head phones cause a kernel panic (among other problems).  Reading the forums and bug lists, this might not be due to these specific head phones.

I have now installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Asus K53s series and the head phones are both visible and connect, however, there is no sound.  With Ubuntu 11.04, sound was possible but only low quality (HSP/HFP) no high quality (A2SP).  With Ubuntu 12.04, both HSP/HFP and A2SP show up in the options but when I switch to the head phones as output in the sound preferences there is no sound.

Im using a Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode).  hciconfig shows the following:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: AE:2D:22:00:FF:00  ACL MTU: 344:12  SCO MTU: 180:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:814 acl:0 sco:0 events:32 errors:0
    TX bytes:634 acl:0 sco:0 commands:32 errors:0
```

There seems to be bug here.  Has anyone got these headphones working with both high/low qualities of sound?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My s305 is working (almost) perfectly on Ubuntu 12.04 (fresh install) but I couldn't get it to work on 11.10, even the low quality.

More interestingly, I can connect the headphone to the pc and my phone at the same time. Pulseaudio sends the sound through A2DP and the phone is connected through HSP/HFP. Although the sound works with HSP/HFP, it sounds kind of hollow (just loud but not good at all). The play and call button are working fine but I can't get the forward and backward ones to work (at least with rythmbox) though typing the keyboard is much faster than reaching for my right ear :D.

My laptop has a built-in bluetooth so I'm not sure if your problem is related to the dongle.

By the way, do when you listen to a music through your headphone do you hear the pitch changing sometimes? Or I need to check my ear? :D